# JDBC prepareStatement doesn't work

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use the `prepareStatement` function. The code is below. After it executes, it returns me a bunch of `vlicense` strings instead of the values.

When the code finishing the `statement.setString()`, the statement becomes:

```
select 'vlicense' from Vehicle
```

However, it needs to be:

```
select vlicense from Vehicle
```

without the quotation marks. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

```
statement = oConnection.prepareStatement("select ? from Vehicle");
String tempString = "vlicense";
statement.setString(1, tempString);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use parameter markers for column names, table names, data type names, or basically anything that isn't data.

Comment: And can you please check what's the issue for me?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78015586/586439

Answer (score 2):

When you add a bind variable to a statement like this it is escaped, so that actual SQL string in your example would go to the database as "SELECT 'vlicense' FROM Vehicle', selecting a literal string instead of the column name you want.

You need to concatenate that variable column name into your SQL statement before you prepare it:

```
statement = oConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT " + vlicense + " FROM Vehicle");
```

Bind variables are really for query parameters as opposed to dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

The ? can't be used to specify the fields, just to do some filters in your query like:

```
statement = conn.prepareStatement("select field from Vehicle where name=?");
```

In your case your query is built as:

```
select 'vlicense' from Vehicle
```

which means: GET ME A STRING 'vlicense' FOR EACH RECORD OF 'Vehicle'. And you'll get *n* repeated strings depending on the number of records in your table

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `jdbc`, `prepared-statements` or `mysql`.
It's just a wrong `sql` statement.

If you type:

```
Select 'justanexample' from Vehicle
```

and the table contains 4 lines, you will get 4 times

```
'justanexample'
'justanexample'
'justanexample'
'justanexample'
```

as result.

You did not specify your the table structure, but I guess the 
statement should somehow look like this:

```
select * from Vehicle where license = ?
```