# Is there a way to use NamedParameters before WHERE clause in jdbctemplate

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am running a query like:

```
SELECT COLNAME FROM TABLEA GROUP BY COLNAME;
```

`COLNAME` will be directly provided by the user at times so I want to avoid sql injections in my code. So, I'm wondering whether its possible to write my query like:

```
SELECT ? FROM TABLEA GROUP BY ?;
```

Another option would be to match the user input with all the column names for the table, however, that approach seems like a bad way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JdbcTemplate#queryForObject`

[I found some examples](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

This won't do. Prepared statement are there for replacing values and not column names. You have to build the string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use parameter markers for column names, table names, data
>   type names, or basically anything that isn't data.

[The reply is available here..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942473/1060037)